# Popup Input In Batch? VBS Input Limit Removal?

Tags: batch-file, input, vbscript, popup

I am making a program in command prompt that asks for your input, but in a popup, not in command prompt, then confirms what you typed by showing another popup without input.
Here is the code I have so far.

```
echo wscript.echo inputbox(WScript.Arguments(0),WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\input.vbs" & for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "Input Here:" "Input Collect Program"') do set input=%%a
```

This makes a VBScript file and runs it, and saves the input in the variable %Input%. This would have been perfect but this does not work out because there is a limit to the input box, so I need to either remove the limit or need another way to do this in command prompt batch.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is using `copy con tmp.txt` in the batch file so that you can rightclick the console window, click `Paste`, press `Ctrl-Z` and thus put the input in `tmp.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if .net have same restrictions about input length - i think it should be the String limit - 2,147,483,647,  - characters:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** silent line that start jscript comment ******

:batch
@echo off
setlocal

:: find jsc.exe
set "jsc="
for /r "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\" %%# in ("*jsc.exe") do  set "jsc=%%#"

if not exist "%jsc%" (
   echo no .net framework installed
   exit /b 10
)

if not exist "%~n0.exe" (
   call %jsc% /nologo /r:"Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0" || (
      exit /b %errorlevel% 
   )
)
for /f "delims=" %%# in ('%~n0.exe %*') do echo -%%#-
endlocal & exit /b %errorlevel%

*/

import Microsoft.VisualBasic;
import System;

var input=Interaction.InputBox("Question?","Title","Default Text")

Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Comment: 32768 characters max, just tried it. Interactive inputs are usually (at least should be) limited to prevent exploits I think. Maybe the OP was hitting the command line length limit actually?